# Point of intersection closest to the origin

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, conic-sections, lagrange-multiplier

How do I find the point of intersection of $ +  -  + 2 = 0$ and $^2 = ^2 + ^2$ that is closest to the origin?

I know I have to use the LaGrange multiplier in order to minimize the equation 
$$
(,,) = ^2 + ^2 + ^2.
$$
So I have the following:

- $2 = λ + μ(2)$
- $2 = λ + μ(2)$
- $2 = -λ + μ(-2)$
- $ +  -  + 2 = 0$
- $^2 = ^2 + ^2$

But I keep getting that $ = 0$ which has no solution.

Comment: Your  third equation is wrong, look carefully and see if you can fix it.

Comment: I suspect it is $(-2+\sqrt{2},-2+\sqrt{2},2\sqrt{2}-2)$ by observation.

Comment: But how would I solve this system of equations? How do we know μ ≠ 1?

Comment: How do we know μ ≠ 1 so that y = x?